# Assembly instruction and an extra 2E prefix before its opcode?

Tags: assembly, x86

When I was tracing a piece of assembly program, I encountered an instruction "CALL DWORD PTR CS:[<&KERNEL32.GetPrivateProfileIntA>] with opcode 2E:FF15 84244100! Now I'm interested to know:

1. Though the opcode relevent to Call instruction is EA , why is the opcode mentioned as above used instead?
2. What does 2E: preceding the FF15 refer to?

Comment: The `2E` is `cs` segment register prefix. The `FF15...` opcode is `call   DWORD PTR ds:0x412484`, because `ds` is default segment register for this instruction, when not specified, and the `2E` `cs` prefix will modify that into `call   DWORD PTR cs:0x412484`.  ... why didn't you read the instruction guide instead of asking here? Will you ask for every new instruction you will encounter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2e is the CS segment override.

[`FF /2` is `call r/m32`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html). The destination of the call is in the memory operand.  (i.e. it loads a new EIP from memory).  Without the CS prefix, it would have used the DS segment's base/limit for that addressing mode.

([EA is far jump](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html) so I think you meant E8 which is the opcode for the usual call rel32.)

Comment: thank you.but I guess you mean "DS override"?? As I understood this instruction works with DS as default.

Comment: DS is the default segment. The CS segment override says to use CS instead.